# Extracting year value from mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: excel, date, datetime

I have a very large dataset (100,000+ records) and one of the fields is a date field that is in this format: mm/dd/yyyy. I have tried using "=YEAR(A1)" to get the year value from the column A which has the original date to column B with only the year date. It just gives me a very weird date like "6/31/1905" but my dates are definitely not in that range. Any other advice?

Comment: Are the cells that have the dates formatted as a date?  I'm not sure it matters, but that's the first thought I had.

Comment: not sure what you are asking, if column b has the date then use =Year(B1) or if column a has just the year just retrun the value of column a or in a worst extreme bad way =Year(Date(A1,1,1)).  Read your question again and try to rephrase it

Comment: As Gary's answer indicates, Column B (with the formula =Year(A1)) must be formatted as 'General'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format the cell containing the formula:

```
=YEAR(A1)
```

as **General**

Comment: yup I was definitely missing the formatting part. worked like a charm as soon as I formatted to General